# Nix: Map list of keys to attribute set members

Tags: functional-programming, nix

I'm trying to map a list of attribute names to an attribute set in Nix in a way where the list holds certain keys that are used to create new attribute set members. My simplified high-level objective is that I want to apply the configuration line `users.users.myuser.packages = [pkgs.curl];` to a list of users without code repetition.

I tried something like this:

```hs
> userList = ["foo" "bar]
> users = { users = {}; } 
> builtins.map (u: users.users."${u}" = {}) userList
```

This fails as there is an unexpected `=`. I have a feeling that using `map` is the wrong operation, but I don't know what the name of the functional operation is that I want to execute here.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a list of attribute sets, which you can then convert to a real attribute set:

```hs
    let
        users = ["foo" "bar"];
        wantedPackages = [ "curl" ];
    in
        builtins.listToAttrs (builtins.map(u: { name = u; value = { packages = wantedPackages;}; }) users);
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to create a set describing the relevant configuration and assigning it to `users.users`.

A simplified example that you can execute in Nix repl looks like this:

```hs
let
  userList = [ "foobar" "user2" ];
  sharedConfig = {
    packages = [ "package1" "package2" "package3" ];
  };
  attrsetRepeatValue =
    value:
    userList:
    let
      # Accumulator
      acc = { };
    in
    builtins.foldl' (acc: user: acc // { "${user}" = value; }) acc userList;
in
{
  users = {
    users = attrsetRepeatValue sharedConfig userList;
  };
}
```

It's formatted output from the Nix repl as JSON looks like this:

```json
{
  "users": {
    "users": {
      "foobar": {
        "packages": [
          "package1",
          "package2",
          "package3"
        ]
      },
      "user2": {
        "packages": [
          "package1",
          "package2",
          "package3"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```